# Should I check if the SQLite is open before each transaction?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my database there are many methods, each one is created to retrieve a specific row by passing the ID as a parameter. And, In my App, I need to call these methods to perform certain action on the retrieved data. example of that is, the code posted below. Do I need to check the `SqliteDB.isOpen` before I call these methods.

Java_Code:

```
if (! sqliteDB.isOpen()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "@fetchItemRelativeToFullList(): Sqlite DataBase Was Closed, and it Will Be Opened");
        sqliteDB = mplOpenHelperDB.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "@fetchItemRelativeToFullList(): Sqlite DataBase Is Opened");
    String name = mplOpenHelperDB.getLocationName(itemClickedPos+1);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name of location"+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    DataBaseRow dataBaseRow = new DataBaseRow();
    if (dataBaseRow != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "@fetchItemRelativeToFullList(): Object of DataBaseRow Class Is Created, Not NULL");

        if ( (mplOpenHelperDB.getLocationName(itemClickedPos+1)).equals("") ) {
            Log.i(TAG, "@fetchItemRelativeToFullList: getLocationName Is Empty");
            dataBaseRow.setLocName("NULL");
        }
        else {
            String targetName = mplOpenHelperDB.getLocationName(itemClickedPos+1);
            dataBaseRow.setLocName(targetName);
        }
```

Sample Of DataBase Methods:

```
public String getLocationName(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.rawQuery("SELECT locationName FROM MPLData WHERE "+
                                                BaseColumns._ID+" = "+
                                                Long.toString(id) +" AND locationName IS NOT NULL ", null);
    String r;
    c.moveToFirst();
    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
        return "";
    } else {
      r = c.getString(0);
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return r;       
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing all this, I'd recommend looking into cursorLoaders. They may be a bit much at first, but they are super powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your immediate question is "No".  When you getReadableDatabase(), the db is open.  You are good.

FWIW, I'd guess that you have experience doing db work in some other context (Ruby, PHP, etc).  As David points out you are doing way more work than you need to do.  Have a look at Loaders, ContentProviders and ContentResolvers, FTW.

Comment: FWIW = For what it is worth; FTW = For the win!

Answer (score 1):

No, `getReadableDatabase()` and `getWritableDatabase()` Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened and `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)`, `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)` and/or `onOpen(SQLiteDatabase)` will be called.